# Crashing when a C++ SLOT function attempts to interact with inputs it got from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have something like this causing my program to crash

```
void BackEnd::updateChart(QtCharts::QChartView *view)
{
    QList<QObject*> children = view->children();
}
```

And on the QML side:

```
backend.updateChart(chartView);
```

where "backend" is an instance of the QT object "BackEnd" and "chartView" is an instance of the QML type "ChartView"

I tried running the following on my BackEnd constructor, however that didn't help

```
qRegisterMetaType<QtCharts::QChartView*>();
```

Comment: Have you debugged what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChartView` is not a `QChartView`, `ChartView` is a [DeclarativeChart](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtcharts.git/tree/src/chartsqml2/declarativechart_p.h#n60) that is a `QQuickItem` of the private api that handles the same data of QChartView but it is not a `QChartView`. So the solution is to change `QtCharts::QChartView` to `QQuickItem` or `QObject`.

```
void BackEnd::updateChart(QQuickItem /*or QObject*/ *view)
{
    QList<QObject*> children = view->children();
}
```

if you print view with `qDebug()` you get:

```
QtCharts::DeclarativeChart(0xfoo_address, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 400x300)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish I knew about QDebug before hand.